# Multi line Parameter Overrides Following Parameter - Bash

Tags: bash, unix, quotes

I have a bash script that takes input of a multiline string from another bash script. For example it may look something like this

```
hello
world
```

if I assign the above string to a variable and pass it as a parameter to my script along with other variables

```
script.sh $multi_line_string $foo $bar
```

in my other script, script.sh ill have some like the below snippet to get the parameters and assign them to a variable

```
multi_line=$1
foo=$2
bar=$3
```

but the values of each will be

```
multi_line = hello
foo = world
bar = foo
```

and what im looking for is in script.sh is to have the full string inside of the multiline variable

```
multi_line = hello
             world

foo = foo
bar = bar
```

I understand why this is happening but I want to know how I can prevent the newlines in the variable from being interoperated as another parameter instead of just the one.

Comment: You must quote the variables: `script.sh "$multi_line_string" "$foo" "$bar"` -- that will preserve the whitespace.

Comment: @glennjackman unfortunately that didnt resolve the issue

Comment: Then you'll need to show how script.sh uses the parameters. You have to ensure that your variables are quoted everywhere you use them.